# how can I relink tree node in java

Tags: java, tree, converters

They didn't mention the question that I ask. Only keyword of those questions matches my question.

I test the code and get different results. I have no ideas that the results are different. The original question is here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-a-given-binary-tree-to-doubly-linked-list-set-2/

The answer is correct if I write the code like this;

```
// Start from the rightmost node, traverse  
// back using left pointers. While traversing,  
// change right pointer of nodes 
while (root != null && root.left != null)  
{ 
    node left = root.left; 
    left.right = root; 
    root = root.left; 
}
```

The answer is wrong. I can only print out the first node. This means I didn't modified the right pointer successfully. I don't know why.

```
// Start from the rightmost node, traverse 
// back using left pointers. While traversing, 
// change right pointer of nodes 
        node help = null;
while (root != null && root.left != null) 
{ 
    help = root;
    root.right = help;

    //node left = root.left; 
    //left.right = root; 
    root = root.left; 
}
```

the correct answer can print out all data in the tree.
the incorrect one can only point out the first element, the root in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
root.right = help;
```

should be

```
root.left.right = help;
```